# What is $\mid\text{det}(A,G)\mid$?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, determinant

I am reading [an old paper dated back in 70'](http://biomet.oxfordjournals.org/content/61/2/383.full.pdf), where I encounter this
$$\mid\text{det}(A,G)\mid=(\text{det}\{(A,G)'(A,G)\})^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$

We compute the determinant of a single matrix, don't we? What doest it mean by $\mid\text{det}(A,G)\mid$?

Comment: Are $A$ and $G$ square matrices ?

Comment: @NikitaEvseev No, they aren't.

Comment: Then what kind of object are $A$ and $G$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the dimensions of $A$ and $G$ (as defined in the paper), it appears that $\det(A,G)$ is the determinant of the matrix you get by augmenting $A$ by $G$. The identity you mention would be written as
$$\left|\det(M)\right| = \sqrt{\det (M^\top M)}$$
in modern notation.

Comment: "augment" means "glue together": $\left(\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\3\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{c}4\\5\\6\end{array}\right]\right)=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&4\\2&5\\3&6\end{array}\right]$.

Comment: Thanks for the omission. I've fixed it in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for _pointing out_ the omission, that is ... (Aw, xxxx, it's the Internet!)